# Matching a large number of strings/phrases

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to implement a process, wherein a text file of roughly 50/150kb is uploaded, and matched against a large number of phrases (~10k).

I need to know which phrases match specifically.

A phrase could be "blah blah blah" or just "blah" - meaning I need to take word-boundaries into account, as I don't wish to include infix matches.

My first attempt was to just create a large pre-compiled list of regular expressions that look like `@"\b{0}\b"` (as 10k the phrases are constant - I can cache & re-use this same list against multiple documents);

On my brand-new & very fast PC - this matching is taking 10 seconds+, which I would like to be able to reduce a great deal.

Any advice on how I may be able to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Implement your own binary tree or balanced trees (pages) like indexes in SQL server

Comment: @JesseJames Sorry - you're going to have to explain this one to me a little more!

Comment: Here is a good example and even ready to use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18976/A-simple-Binary-Search-Tree-written-in-C

Comment: @JesseJames Thanks for your help - but I'm still not 100% sure how I'd be able to do this, as I need to match phrases of an unknown number of words... Can you you give me any ideas on implementation? Thanks again.

Comment: Heh, @Dave Bish I cannot explain to you better than link above because my English is bad :(

Comment: I'm sorry I misread the original question. I've written a new answer with a method which is extremely fast: inverted indices, and an implementaion of it (Lucene.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Lucene.NET and the [Shingle Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleFilter.html) as long as you don't mind having a cap on the number of possible words as phrase can have.

```
public class MyAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {       
        return new ShingleFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(new StandardTokenizer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, reader)), 6);
    }
}
```

You can run the analyzer using this utility method.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTerms(Analyzer analyzer, string keywords)
{
    var tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream("content", new StringReader(keywords));
    var termAttribute = tokenStream.AddAttribute<ITermAttribute>();

    var terms = new HashSet<string>();
    
    while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
    {
        var term = termAttribute.Term;
        if (!terms.Contains(term))
        {
            terms.Add(term);
        }
    }

    return terms;
}
```

Once you've retrieved all the terms do an intersect with you words list.

```
var matchingShingles = GetTerms(new MyAnalyzer(), "Here's my stuff I want to match");

var matchingPhrases = phrasesToMatch.Intersect(matchingShingles, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I think you will find this method is much faster than Regex matching and respects word boundries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lucene.Net

This will create a inedx of your text, so that you can make really quick queries against it. This is a "full text index".

This article explains what it's all about:

[Lucene.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29755/Introducing-Lucene-Net)

This library is originally written in java, (Lucene) but there is a port to .NET (lucene.net).

You must take special care while choosing the stemmer. An stemmer takes the "root" of a word, so that several similar words can match (i.e. book and books will match). If you need exact matches, then you should take (or implement) an stemmer which returns the original words without change.

The same stemmer must be used for creating the index and for searching the results.

You must also have a look at the syntax, because it's too powerful and allows for partial matches, exact matches, and so on.

You can also have a look at [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/09/02/using-lucene-net-search-engine-library-in-net-applications.aspx).